# How do i remove _dc parameter from sencha touch 2 request

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

In every sencha request there are an extra parameter _dc. Please have took at the following image.
[image: Look every request has _dc parameter]

I want to remove this parameter for every request. So, please help me to do that.

Thank You...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_dc - this is "disable cache". You can disable this noCache parameter in proxy in your store\model. Example:

```
Ext.define('your model name', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

   fields: [...],

   proxy: {
      url: 'getcandidateblock',
      noCache: false
   }
})
```

But it's bad idea for ALL get requests to server.

Comment: @Semin why it is bad idea ?

Comment: @Abhijit Muke, will be disabled caching for requests

Answer (score 0):

Use '**[noCache](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-noCache)**' config in your store's proxy

**To disable the '_dc'** query param, set this to **false**.

From Sencha Doc,

***noCache*** - Disable caching by adding a unique parameter name to the request. Set to false to allow caching. Defaults to true.